# PDCurses scrolling issue

Tags: scroll, buffer, ncurses, curses, pdcurses

Whenever I need a large data output in a console I just use setconsolescreenbuffersize() so I can always scroll back if amount of data exceeds the size of console.

However, when using pdcurses I can't seem to make it so a window remembers its contents. If I set it to be scrollable and try to scroll back I get empty lines. I've looked at WINDOW data structure and haven't found anything resembling data buffer. Do I have to code a buffer for curses window myself?

Here is an example program. It creates a pad, prints numbers from 1 to 100 and after that is supposed to scroll back to number one. However, instead of numbers there is simply nothing.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    WINDOW  *w;
    int     i;

    if (initscr() != NULL)
    {
            if ((w = newpad(25,80)) != NULL) 
            {
                    scrollok(w,TRUE);
                    for (i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++) 
                    {
                            Sleep (50);
                            wprintw(w,"%d\n",i);
                            prefresh(w,0,0,0,0,24,79);
                    }
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Sleep (50);
                        wscrl (w, -1);
                        prefresh(w,0,0,0,0,24,79);
                    }
            }
            endwin();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PDcurses (like any other curses application) only remembers what is on the screen.  If you need data which is off-screen, yes - you have to manage that yourself.